# Adding EventFiringWebDriver to Selenium Framework

Tags: c#, selenium, event-handling, webdriver

I need help with expanding my already build Selenium framework with WebDriver. I want to add eventHandlers that use `EventFiringWebDriver` on top of my code to add event for each action triggered by WebDriver for logging purposes. 
To begin with, I will try to clearly present code flow.

Test starts...
Step 1. `CspTestBase`

```
public class CspTestBase : CommonElements
    {

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void Init()
        {
            Initialize(); <- Code to init driver.
        // more code here. 
        LoginPage.Goto();
        LoginPage.LoginAs(TestConfig.Username).WithPassword(TestConfig.Password).Login();
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            Close();
        }
```

When it jumps to `Init` method. This class holds all methods that directly require WebDriver instance.

```
public static class Driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver Instance { get; private set; }


        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Instance = new TestDriverFactory().CreateDriver(); <- Next step 
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            Instance.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

            //Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }
```

Then when WebDriver `Instance` is created:

```
 public class TestDriverFactory
    {
        public IWebDriver CreateDriver()
        {
            return new TestBase().Create(
                new LocalDriverConfig(
                    TestConfig.Browser));
        }
    }
```

And when it finally comes to creating actual driver:

```
public class TestBase 
    {
        private static IWebDriver _driver;
        //string env;
        private DesiredCapabilities _capabilities;

        public IWebDriver Create(LocalDriverConfig config)
        {
            switch (config.Browser)
            {
                case "Chrome":
                    _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Utilities");
                    break;

                case "Firefox":
                    SetFirefoxCapabilities();

                    //_driver = new FirefoxDriver(_capabilities);
                    break;
                ...
        private void SetFirefoxCapabilities()
        {
        ...
         _capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
            //FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            //options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Warning);

            _capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile);
            //capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, options);
            EventFiringWebDriver firingDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
            // copy the profile for ommiting duplicate references 
            firingDriver.ExceptionThrown += firingDriver_TakeScreenshotOnException;
            _driver = firingDriver;
        }

        private void firingDriver_TakeScreenshotOnException(object sender, WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            TakeScreenshot();
        }
```

As you can see, I'm using `EventFiringWebDriver` already but I want to have it done properly to save me as much work as possible. 
I did some reading and looked up solutions but these were simple or in Java. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand the question here. I am no C# literate, but skimming through the code you shared, gives me the impression that you are pretty much doing it in the right manner [ except for the fact that I would have the TestDriverFactory.CreateDriver() create a raw WebDriver instance and pass it on internally to a separate private method which would wrap a EventFiringWebDriver instance around it along with a listener and then return it back.

Comment: Maybe you can also take a look at the unit tests and see if that helps https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/test/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriverTest.cs

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, I pretty much got it working.